# Where can I find missing design view?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I made the design like the picture below. However, I have no idea where can I edit the design. The design tab is gone from the solution explorer. I still can see the design when I run the program.

[image: Design]

[image: Solution Explorer, sorry about the language]

Where can I find my design at?

This is how looks like when I press 'show all files'

[image: show all files]

Comment: If you click the Show All Files button on the toolbar of the Solution Explorer, can you expand the node for Form1.vb and what does it display?

Comment: sorry but could you show the picture of 'show all files button' I really can't find it

Comment: There aren't all that many buttons on the toolbar of the Solution Explorer so I shouldn't really have to show you. Maybe the tooltip says something else in your local version but it would mean the same thing: show all the project files in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: yeah I just changed the language and I found. I edit the question and upload the picture that I press 'show all files'

Comment: Does closing and re-opening the solution have any effect?

Comment: You can check following reference: [Windows form has disappeared in Visual Studio form designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073966/windows-form-has-disappeared-in-visual-studio-form-designer)

Answer (score 0):

All the expected files are present but, for some reason, VS is not recognising that item as a form. It just so happens that I had a similar situation recently, although there's no guarantee that the cause and, therefore, the solution will be the same.

What I did was, in the Solution Explorer, drag the form item onto the project, depress the the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and then drop to create a copy. If it works as in my case, you should see that the copy has a different icon, indicating that it is a form. I then deleted the original item and renamed the new item to remove the " - Copy". from the name. Everything worked as expected thereafter.

It might not hurt to create a copy of your solution folder before doing this if you are not using source control, just in case you make matters worse by accident.