# Unable to find winform in winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a Windows Forms project that opens up one form then a second one when the program runs. I can find the Windows Form Designer for the first form but the second form seems to be gone. It should be Form1.cs, I know this because there is a form1.Designer.cs that I can open up and make changes to, and then when I run the program those changes are reflecting in the form1 form. Can someone help me out in finding where I can find the actual form in the Windows Form Designer so I can make changes to the controls on this form? Thanks in advance..... also my apologies if I referred to anything using the wrong name, I'm relatively new at this.

Comment: Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs are referring to the same class. They are one class which is split into two files. Are you saying there is another form like Form2 and you can not find it in the project?

Comment: No, more like Form1.cs isn't behaving like I would expect it to be. From my experience if you have a form in your project, by double clicking on the #formName#.cs then it brings the actual visual form up so you can add controls and things of the like. When I double click on my Form1.cs it brings up code. Am I misunderstanding something or shouldn't it bring up my visual Form1 so I can see the controls and such on it?

Comment: maybe there's some inheritance. it's very easy to find by the find tools or find all reference function.

Comment: Right click Form1.cs, choose `View Designer` from the menu.

Comment: the "View Designer" option isn't available when I right click Form1.cs

Comment: Maybe you have edited Form1.Designer.cs by hand and messed up something...But unless you can provide the source for both files and we can use to reproduce, there is no way to guess what is really going wrong.

Comment: Thanks to all that contributed here. I found the answer to my problem in this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941692/unable-to-get-the-designer-view-window-back-using-windows-forms-with-visual-stud

In the end tracked it down to a problem in the .csproj file. There is a item group that specifies what is compiled. Within the item group tag, for my form it had ...

<Compile Include="AreaChart.cs" />
it needed...

<Compile Include="AreaChart.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought that my previous comment had fixed the problem but I found that after I made the change to the .csproj file VS would just undo the change and I still couldn't view Form1.cs in design mode. I got to playing around with it and I found that the cause of not being able to view it in design mode was due to having two classes defined at the top of the code for Form1.cs. After I moved the two classes to a new class file within my project I was able to look at the design mode of Form1.cs and make changes to the controls on it.