# I lost my form tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am new to coding and made a pretty bad mistake I belive, or every time I make it I can never fix it, and I have never been able to find the fix online, AT ALL, I opened my program (Visual Studio 2017) and had no tabs, including my forms, I relaunched and I can't find how to get my tabs, all I get from the solution explorer is the code, and I can not right click the form on the solution explorer all it says is "show code", please help

Comment: Might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941692/unable-to-get-the-designer-view-window-back-using-windows-forms-with-visual-stud) (Second answer)

Comment: What kind of project do you have?

Comment: Lars, its is a C# project, if thats what you are asking.

and JNevill, I can't figure out how ot fix it based on that fourm, in the best answers file it had 1 line, mine has 94...

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking about.  WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net, etc?  Screen shot might help.

Comment: Sorry.  I have VS-2017 open, and I have 4 window "panes" showing, each chock-a-block full of tabs (Solution Explorer/TeamExplore/etc in one pane, Output/Stack/Error List/etc in another, Toolbox/Properties/etc in another and all my editing sessions in the main pane).  What tabs are you talking about?  The View menu (and View->Other Windows) is a good way to get things to appear.  When you are debugging, Debug->Windows is handy).

Comment: it is windows form app, sorry I did't understand lol

Comment: flydog57, I am looking for the designer form tab, the one that shows all the buttons, pictures, or whatever, I have had this problem before with it being my fault, I believe to simulate it if you would like, just click the X on the designer form 1 tab (top left of the middle box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done WinForms in a long time, pretty sure it used be be hotkey <kbd>F7</kbd>.
However upon searching it seems that Visual Studio has removed this hotkey (not sure when), further more searching I found this:

> Tools -> Options -> Environment - > Keyboard

and find the `View.ToggleDesigner` command, set the `Use new shortcut` in - to Windows Forms Designer, press <kbd>F7</kbd> in the Press shortcut keys - and click on `Assign`.

Comment: Cool!  I've been using VS since the original VS.NET beta in 2001 and never noticed that before.  It's <Shift>+<F7> with my key bindings.

Comment: I assigned it, all it did was it seems to reload the code, or almost reopen it...

Comment: @JLW1808, would be great if you could edit your question and provide us some images on what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the window "that shows all the buttons, pictures, or whatever", then it's called the "Toolbox".  That window contains all the widgets that you drag onto your form.

> Choose View -> Toolbox

(with my key-bindings, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)

If it's the window "that shows all ***your*** buttons, pictures, or whatever", that's call the form's "Designer" (i.e., the window onto which you drag widgets from the toolbox).  To get that:

- Double-click the form name in the Solution Explorer
- If that didn't open the Designer window, while the form's code is displayed,...

> Choose View->Designer

(in my key bindings, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

The "Designer" and "Code" options are available *only* if the form (or other designable artifact) is visible.

Comment: its the actual form, not the toolbox, or solution explorer, its not in the view, most people get it back form the solution explorer, but when I right click it there is only view code

Comment: Oh, you get the form by double-clicking on the form name in the solution explorer.  If that doesn't work, you will get a very obscure error message.  Let us know what it says, and we can figure it out.  Anyone who has done WinForms work has probably hit that error before.

Comment: when I double click it, just code shows up, and there is no error... and I am clicking the designer form one.

Comment: I don't even see designer in view

Comment: Every Form has this structure: FromName.cs (general form, double-click opens the designer tab), FormName.Designer.cs (double-click opens the generated code-behind) and FromName class (in VS 2017 no extension is shown) that contains the code you add (event handlers, etc.)

Comment: Can you upload a picture of VS showing the issue you're having?

Comment: You won't see it unless your [FormName].cs file is open and is the window you are working on.  Open your form, pull down View, and the top two entries should be Code and Designer