# Form1.cs [Design] disappeared

Tags: c#, winforms

I think I goofed up and my WinForms designer is missing now. I noticed this in my `Form1.Designer.cs` file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
```

I deleted one line from this file because I accidentally added an extra button. I deleted it from the GUI designer but the code still remained. So I just deleted it.

My application compiles and runs correctly. But after poking around in Visual Studio for 20 minutes now & Googling I can't seem to get `Form1.cs [Design]` file to come back.

Basically this file (pic taken from Google)

[image]

The `Form1.cs [Design]` displayed some sort of error but I closed the tab. Now I can't seem to even get the tab back to see the problem.

Comment: Are you able to revert the change in source control?

Comment: @mjwills Unfortunately not, this was just a local project not in a git repo.

Comment: The file is probably still in the Project directory. Open it up with Notepad or a similar editor, compare the content with an another `FormX.Designer.cs`, see what's missing and add it back. If it's the `InitializeComponent()` method content, you're probably out of luck. You'll need to add back all the controls, giving them the original names. Just some more work to do. Unless you can still `CTRL-Z` yourself out of trouble.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Posting this to help others who may have this issue. The problem was that I created a class within my `Form1.cs` file BEFORE my `public partial class Form1 : Form` class. As described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40243490/8887398

A key indicator this might be your problem is if your form looks like this in your solution explorer:
[image]

Notice the icon for Form1.cs looks like a regular C# file. This is how it should look if it's a form:

[image]

You can clearly see the difference in the icon. Simply making sure the `public partial class Form1 : Form` class was first in the file instantly brought back the ability for me to open the `Form1.cs [Design]` with a simple double click.

Comment: Thanks, worked fine for me. Just for those who have the same and who don't see the designer back instantly after the changes are made : exclude the cs form file from the projet and include it again. The file icon should update and the designer would show again by double-clicking on cs file.

Comment: Reopening the .sln file along with the Dependencies made the Form Icon visible. And then double clicking the Icon opened the Form in Design format.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use this post to show my solution.
I have a solution with 30 projects, 5 of them are WinForms apps. Everything being equal - it was possible to design forms in four of those, only one was "code only".

What worked for me was:

- go to the properties of the problematic project
- change the output type to "Console application"
- save
- change the output type back to "Windows application"
- save

[image: Change output type]

Comment: Very helpful answer! For me the problem occured when I cloned my repo from GitHub on another PC. The original project had no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. close visual studio 2022 (or whatever version)
2. open project using from whatever folder you are using if you haven't already
3. scroll over to "solution explorer" (this is located on the right side of the visual studio interface menu)
   this is the file structure:
   [this is my files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwtzh.png)

4. then double-click on `music-database-app-sql.sln`, obv your file structure will be different--> new interface will show
5. now right click on `form1.cs`
6. click `View Designer`
7. done! now you can mod the interface all you want